# Инициализация класса с индексатором

Tags: c#

Задали вопрос на собеседовании. 
Возможно ли инициализировать экземпляр класса с индексатором блоком инициализатора?

```
class MyClass
{
    private int[] array = new int[5];

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[index];
        }
        set
        {
            array[index] = value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Допустима ли чисто теоретически такая инициализация?
        MyClass my = new MyClass(){1,2,3,4,5};

        //my[0] = 1;
        //my[1] = 2;
        //my[2] = 3;
        //my[3] = 4;
        //my[4] = 5;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Если реализовать два интерфейса iEnumerable и IEnumerator:

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    private int[] array = new int[5];
    int index;

    // Индексатор. 
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get    // Аксессор.
        {
            return array[index];
        }
        set    // Мутатор.
        {
            array[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if(index == array.Length - 1)
        {
            Reset();
            return false;
        }

        index++;
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        index = -1;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return array[index];
        }
    }
}
```

В блоке инициализатора VS на каждое число ругается:

> CS1061 'MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'MyClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Как можно реализовать метод `Add` в классе, чтобы конструкция инициализатора работала? Или же это недопустимо?

Comment: А вот так подойдёт: http://ideone.com/YGktSh?

Comment: @VladD Запись с индексами достаточно громоздкая. Я конечно сомневаюсь в том что огромные блоки инициализатора вообще где-либо применимы, но здесь конкретика заданного вопроса скорее всего критична. Собеседование хоть и провалено, вопрос то остался.

Comment: замените int[] на List<int> тогда просто вызываете метод Add() списка, либо используйте метод Resize

Comment: А что мешает просто добавить метод Add?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если не нужно использовать `foreach loop`, а нужна только инициализация значений блоком инициализатора, то достаточно просто унаследоваться от `IEnumerable`, по сути не реализуя сам метод `GetEnumerator()` и добавить метод `Add()`:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable
{
    private List<int> array = new List<int>();

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[index];
        }
        set
        {
            array[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        this.array.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Такой класс можно инициализировать следующим образом:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass { 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
```

Comment: То что и надо было, спасибо

Comment: Где бы найти эту информацию, что конструкция "{ }" в строке объявления экземпляра класса запрашивает метод Add? Если не заглядывать в intellisence?